# Ajax not working in Chrome or IE but does in FireFox

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm having some unexpected issues on one of my sites, I thought my Ajax was working, but then I noticed it only works in firefox.

When debugging in the Chrome console I see this:

```
invoke.js:1 Console was cleared
main.js:42 in Startnull
prompt.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'originalPrompt' has already been declared
/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
main.js:42 in Startnull
prompt.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'originalPrompt' has already been declared
mc_ns_26.06.2018_728x90_8_en.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
main.js:42 in Startnull
prompt.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'originalPrompt' has already been declared
1588423983.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid/common/browser-polyfill.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/atoms.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/polyfills.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/escape.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/playback.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/record.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
jquery-3.5.1.js:10099 POST https://www.quiz-griz.com/30-how-well-do-you-know-the-vampire-diaries-characters/ajax-answer.php 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10099
ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9682
AjaxRequest @ global.js:11
AnswerQuestion @ global.js:67
onclick @ (index):86
```

The issue is here:

```
jquery-3.5.1.js:10099 POST https://www.quiz-griz.com/30-how-well-do-you-know-the-vampire-diaries-characters/ajax-answer.php 404 (Not Found)
```

It's trying to load my ajax file after the rewritten .htaccess url, the location is really here `/ajax/ajax-answer.php` on my server and in my javascript code.

This is my code where the file location is referenced:

```
function AnswerQuestion(el) {
  const $el = $(el);
  //alert($el.data('question-id'));
  if ($el.hasClass('disabled'))
    return;
  $el.addClass('disabled');
  const url = '/ajax/ajax-answer.php';
  let pars = {
    answer: $('input[name=questions]:checked', '#question-form').val(),
    takenQuizId: $el.data('taken-quiz-id'),
    quizId: $el.data('quiz-id'),
    questionId: $el.data('question-id'),
  };
  AjaxRequest(url, pars, function(response) {
    // success goes here
    $el.removeClass('disabled');
    console.info("SUCCESS->", response);
    location.reload();
  },
  function (response) {
    // fail goes here
    $el.removeClass('disabled');
    console.info("FAIL->", response);
  });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#question-form input").on("change", function(){
    $(".btn").removeClass('disabled');
  });
});
```

Which is working fine in firefox, but in Chrome and Internet Explorer it does not want to work.

I can't think of what to try, is there anything I can tweak to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not it was a cache issue on both browsers! once cleared it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I had an experience with this problem that might help. In my project, I was given access to the ajax request page to the admin user, but I was testing the functionality with a regular user, without access to that page. So ajax was not responding as expected. And I was curiously saying that it only worked in other browsers, because in other browsers I was logged in as the administrator user and only in firefox as the unprivileged user. That was hilarious, wasn't it?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).